# activate git cli autocomplete for zsh on macos

Tags: git, macos, autocomplete, command-line-interface, zsh

New Mac ships with git but cli auto completion is not activated.

For reference:

- `git --version`: git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
- `$SHELL --version`: zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
- Mac M1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bzsh%5D+autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

I searched for this for too long. Hopefully this helps the next person.

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Then run this command to update your shell:
`source ~/.zshrc`